# Ajax post request sometimes doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to send an ajax post request to see whether the user is logged in or not before proceeding. here's my code:

client side:

```js
$("#startquiz").click(function() {
  var ch = "";
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "load.php",
    data: {
      ch: ch
    },
    success: function(response) {
      if (response == "ok") {
        $("#cont").show();
        $("#overlay").hide();
      } else if (response == "login") {
        $("#overlay").html("Please login or create an account to take the quiz");
      } else {
        $("#overlay").html(response);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

load.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['ch'])){
    if(isset($_SESSION['myusername'])){echo "ok";}
    else{echo "login";}
    exit();
}else{echo "no post request";}
?>
```

I tested the page from my laptop and mobile and it works correctly (if logged in the quiz opens, if not it asks them to log in). but I tested the website on other peoples devices and some got "no post request" as the output. what causes this? what makes the post request sometimes not sent? and what should I do to fix it and make the ajax work for everyone correctly?

Comment: You should probably use `!empty($_POST)` instead of checking the `ch` variable

Comment: @reem-rizk - as per your code it shows "ch" value looks blank

Comment: @luca could this be the reason why the ajax works on some devices and doesn't on others?

Comment: @jaydp could this be the reason why the ajax works on some devices and doesn't on others?